# one codebehind method handles two distinct dropdowns - isn't supposed to

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, drop-down-menu, code-behind

I have one page with two dropdownlists with different IDs and in my codebehind I have two distinct methods, one for each dropdownlist, with distinct names and handlers.

BUT, in my codebehind, only one dropdownlist calls it's method - and sometimes it calls both methods! - while the other dropdownlist never calls its method.

I tried cleaning the infamous "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder
I tried rebuilding the solution

but the problem persists
= (

Do you have any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to set the `AutoPostBack="True"` on one of the dropdownlists

Result: the second dropdownlist method is only called after a postback is triggered by changing the first dropdownlist value.

Simlpe as that !